# Iterate through each column in a dataframe and perform a compare

Tags: scala, apache-spark, for-loop, if-statement, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a compare function from table to table on a dataframe and I want to see if I can create a quicker process for the if statement. I want to be able to iterate through each column in the dataframe and I'm curious if I can use a column position or something instead of making a configuration for each column name. When I have 100 columns I don't want to declare each column name in the conf file, so can someone please point me in the direction of a quicker method?

Conf File:

```
matching_col1= member_id
matching_col2= activation_idn
matching_col3= addition_dt
```

Actual Code:

```scala
 val mismatches_df_1 = Df1_renamed_matching.except(Df2_renamed_matching)
    if (mismatches_df_1.count() > 0) {

if(DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col1 != DF2_with_err_cols.matching_col1)
{insert into mismatches_df_1 VALUES (DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col1 as matching_col1, ERR_COLUMN                         
= matching_col1, ERR_VALUE_SOURCE = DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col1, ERR_DESCRIPTION = 
matching_col1 + " does not match value in " + source_db_jdbc_table_name2  )}
else{ insert into mismatches_df_1 VALUES(DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col1 as matching_col1) 
  ....
if(DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col14 != DF2_with_err_cols.matching_col14)
{insert into mismatches_df_1 VALUES (DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col14 as matching_col14, 
ERR_COLUMN = matching_col14, ERR_VALUE_SOURCE = DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col14, ERR_DESCRIPTION 
= matching_col14 + " does not match value in " + source_db_jdbc_table_name2  )}
else{ insert into mismatches_df_1 VALUES(DF1_with_err_cols.matching_col14 as matching_col14) }
```

so instead of doing this 1-100 times per table/dataframe is there a way to create a loop? or for each type of function based off the column's position?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please add schema & sample data for each of these DataFrames - Df1_renamed_matching, Df2_renamed_matching, DF1_with_err_cols & DF2_with_err_cols, mismatches_df_1 , input & expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object DataFramesExcept extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._
  case class Sale(
                   corp:    String,
                   product: String,
                   data:    Long,
                   group:   String,
                   sales:   Long,
                   market:  String
                 )

  val df = Seq(
    Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "A", 100, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Eli", 43831, "B", 100, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Sut", 43831, "A", 80, "I"),
    Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "C", 50, "C or D"),
    Sale("A", "Api", 43831, "D", 50, "C or D"),
    Sale("B", "Konkurent2", 43831, "C", 40, "C or D")
  ).toDF()

  val dfE = Seq(
    Sale("Z", "Eli", 43833, "A", 100, "M"),
    Sale("Z", "Eli", 43833, "B", 100, "M"),
    Sale("Z", "Sut", 43833, "A", 80, "M"),
    Sale("Z", "Api", 43833, "C", 50, "M"),
    Sale("Z", "Api", 43833, "D", 50, "M"),
    Sale("Z", "Konkurent2", 43831, "C", 40, "M")
  ).toDF()

  val cols = df.columns.toList

  cols foreach(c => {
    if(df.select(c).except(dfE.select(c)).rdd.isEmpty() == false) {
      println(s"$c is not empty")
    } else {
      println(s"$c is empty")
    }
  })
// result
//  corp is not empty
//  product is empty
//  data is empty
//  group is empty
//  sales is empty
//  market is not empty

}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to ADD EXPLANATION and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: so does the column positioning work like df.columns(0), df.columns(1), etc? @mvasyliv

Comment: please, see example. I need in details description task.